# Pass a class name (not an instantiated object) as method parameter during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Do not know if this is possible but I need to pass a class name (one of several hundred I have) as a parameter to a method.  Each class is a form that contains fields that I am populating. I have the common methods in a common class called Forms. And what I want to do is pass a class name (of the form) to a method in the Forms class which then instantiates and then calls the AddData() method (which adds data to the form). Everything I have found talks about the Activator.CreateInstance(Type t) but it returns a Type object which cannot call the AddData() method.

Process flow:

1. Call FillForm.AutoFill() from UI for the selected form (class name).
2. Call Form.AddData() which instantiates the form and passes in the data retrieved from SQL and UI form fields.
3. Return the completed form to the UI.

I would like to do is when the form is selected on the UI (SQL list of forms) it passes the class name to the FillForm which does something like this:

```
var form = new Form<T>()
var fdata = await form.AddData(GetSqlData(user), inputData)
//AddData uses the appropriate form class
SaveDocument(fdata);
```

But I am not sure how to implement it in Forms.

I really do not want to use a switch statement as it could have up to 600 cases and is not extensible.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type t)` does not return a `Type`, it returns an `Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_)

Comment: Correct.  I got caught up with Type.  It does return an Object.

Answer (score 0):

The following two patterns are presented.

1.
Create an interface with the AddData method.

```
public interface IGoodForm
{
    DataTable AddData(DataTable sqlData, DataTable inputData);
}
```

Implement the IGoodForm interface on each form.

```
 public partial class GoodForm : Form, IGoodForm
{
    ~~~

    public DataTable AddData(DataTable sqlData, DataTable inputData)
    {
        var result = new DataTable();

        return result;
    }
    
    ~~~
}
```

Call the following process.

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var inputData = new DataTable();

var type1 = Type.GetType("Namespace.GoodForm");
var instance1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type1) as IGoodForm;
var result1 = instance1.AddData(dataTable, inputData);
```

2. 

No interface is required and the following processing is called.

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var inputData = new DataTable();

var type2 = Type.GetType("Namespace.GoodForm");
var instance2 = Activator.CreateInstance(type2);
var param2 = new object[] { dataTable, inputData };
var result2 = type2.GetMethod("AddData").Invoke(instance2, param2);
```